# Filter text between two special characters

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

For example I have those strings:

```
"qwe/qwe/qwe/qwe//qwe/somethinghere_blabla.exe"
"qwe/qwe/q//we/qwe//qwe/somethingother_here_blabla.exe"
"qwe/qwe/qwe/qwe//qwe/some_numbers_here_blabla.exe"
```

Now I want to get the text between the last '/' and the last '_'.
So the outcome would be:

```
"somethinghere"
"somethingother_here"
"some_numbers_here"
```

What is the easiest and clearest way to do this?

I have no idea how to do this, should I split them in '/' and '_', so do this apart? I couldn't think of any way how to do it.

Maybe scan the string from the end till it reaches its first '/' and '_'? Or is there an easier and faster way? Because it has to scan ~10.000 strings.

```
string[] words = line.Split('/', '_'); //maybe use this? probably not
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string s = "qwe/qwe/q//we/qwe//qwe/somethingother_here_blabla.exe";
int last_ = s.LastIndexOf('_');
if (last_ < 0) // _ not found, take the tail of string
    last_ = s.Length;
int lastSlash = s.LastIndexOf('/');
string part = s.Substring(lastSlash + 1, last_ - lastSlash - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is [`string.LastIndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var start = line.LastIndexOf('/') + 1;
var end = line.LastIndexOf('_');

var result = line.Substring(start, end - start);
```

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ way:

```
var str = "qwe/qwe/qwe/qwe//qwe/somethinghere_blabla.exe";
var newStr = new string(str.Reverse().SkipWhile(c => c != '_').Skip(1).TakeWhile(c => c != '/').Reverse().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "qwe/qwe/qwe/qwe//qwe/some_numbers_here_blabla.exe";
var start = string.lastIndexOf("/");
var end = string.lastIndexOf("_");
var result = string.substring(start + 1, end);
```

Note: above code does not handle error if string does not have / or _ after a last slash